# Подскажите тип ссылок

Tags: парсер

Есть страница http://ark.intel.com где ссылки каталога реализованы непонятным для меня способом.
Например, второй уровень выглядит в html так:

```
    <div class="row category-row">
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6  col-lg-4 product-category SolidStateDrives" data-order="0" data-panel-key="ConsumerSSDs">
                <span class="name">Consumer SSDs</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6  col-lg-4 product-category SolidStateDrives" data-order="0" data-panel-key="EnthusiastSSDs">
                <span class="name">Enthusiast SSDs</span>
            </div>
           .........

</div>
```

Я убрал несколько пунктов чтобы укоротить листинг.

Что это за ссылки, как они работают?

UPD
Если у меня возникнет потребность спарсить сайт, где навигация построена на подобных ссылках, подскажите пожалуйста, с чего следует начать. Я посмотрел phpQuery, CURL, Scrapy... Технологий много, но я не понимаю что подходит, что не подходит. Сориентируйте, плз.

Comment: `для решения проблемы` - какой проблемы?

Comment: CSS-селектор будет примерно таким: `.category-row > .product-category > .name` и по нему получите теги span с "Consumer SSDs" и "Enthusiast SSDs"

Comment: Просто javascript